# How to define where clause for ExecuteDelete/ExecuteUpdate methods of EF core 7 with generic type properties?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have a generic repository with the following definition :

```
public class DataRepository<TEntity, TEntityIdType> : IDataRepository<TEntity, TEntityIdType>where TEntity : class , IEntity<TEntityIdType>, new()
```

```
public interface IEntity<T>{T _EntityId {get; set;}}
```

I want to implement Delete method of my repository by using ExecuteDelete method of EF Core 7 which is more efficient than querying the DB for specific instance and remove it.

So i tried something like :

```
var deletedItems = await m_dbContext.Set<TEntity>.Where(entity => 
                                                entity._EntityId == idToDelete).ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

idToDelete is a variable of type TEntityIdType which i get as a parameter of the Delete method of the repository.

The problem is that generic type TEntityIdType does not have overloaded operator == .
So the above implementation does not compile. I tried to use method Equals inside Where clause instead of operator == but EF Core failed to translate this code to proper Where clause of SQL query.

What can i do in this situation ?
Thank you.

Comment: How did you try `Equals`?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of the patterns that you're using and wheather your logic requires only checking by Id. However, for more flexibility, you can implement the methods as below.

```
public int BulkDelete(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query)
{
    return this.context.Set<TEntity>().Where(query).ExecuteDelete();
}

public int BulkUpdate(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query, Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>, SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>>> expression)
{
    return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(query).ExecuteUpdate(expression);
}
```

Of course you will use the async versions but this allows you to write any conditions that you wish.

The delete method can then be called by e.g.

```
var deletedItems = DataRepository<User>().BulkDelete(user => user.Id == 3);
```

Comment: The problem is to use operator ==  on the generic type of the Id..

Answer (score 0):

Add an **IEquatable constraint** for **IEntity** in **IDataRepository** interface and in **DataRepository** implementation

```
IEntity<TEntityIdType> where TEntityIdType : IEquatable<TEntityIdType>
```

and change **==** to **Equals**;

```
var deletedItems = await m_dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(entity => entity._EntityId.Equals(idToDelete)).ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

Also, have a look at the [Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find?view=efcore-7.0).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this solution before i post my question. It was not so easy because i needed to update a lot of code. But the bottom line LINQ can not translate the Equals of IEquatable to the legal where clause of SQL as well.. I got a runtime exception.

Comment: Find method doesn't work with the linq queries..

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async Task<int> Update(Expression< Func<T, bool>> criteria, Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<T>, SetPropertyCalls<T>>> prop)
 {
     _context.Set<T>().Where(criteria).ExecuteUpdate(prop);
     return 1;
 }
```

Comment: call it like 
 [HttpDelete("{id}")]
 public  async Task<IActionResult> CreateShoppingMateImage(int id)
 {
   
   var x= ;
    return Ok(await  _data.Update(x=>x.Id == id,l =>l.SetProperty(x => x.IsActive, false)));
 }