# How to use EF Core 8's ExecuteUpdate() and ExecuteDelete() in a generic repository while keeping its interface agnostig from EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, ef-core-8.0

I'm developing a web application using .NET 8 and Clean Architecture.
There I'm trying to implement a generic repository that includes two methods for the bulk-update and bulk-delete
that use EF Core 8's `ExecuteUpdate()` and `ExecuteDelete()` methods, so that I can update/delete the database without being forced to select the entries that must be deleted in advance.

**MyRepository.cs** (located in the Infrastructure Layer)

```
public class MyRepository<TEntity> : IMyRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity, new()
{
    protected readonly IMyDataContext DataContext;

    protected MyRepository(IMyDataContext dataContext)
    {
        DataContext = dataContext;
    }

    // src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75799111/5757823
    public int BulkUpdate(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query, Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>, SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>>> expression)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(query).ExecuteUpdate(expression);
    }

    public int BulkDelete(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query)
    {
        return this.context.Set<TEntity>().Where(query).ExecuteDelete();
    }
}
```

The code sample above needs to include the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query` namespace to use the `SetPropertyCalls` class in the `BulkUpdate()`method.

In my understanding, the according interface `IMyRepository` must be located in the Application Layer
since it's going to be used from most of my Application Services.

**IMyRepository.cs** (located in the Application Layer)

```
public interface IMyRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity, new()
{
    int BulkUpdate(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query, Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>, SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>>> expression);

    int BulkDelete(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query);
}
```

To achieve this, I would have to include the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query` namespace also in the interface.
But in my understanding, the Application Layer should be technology-agnostic, i.e. it's not allowed to include `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` there.

How can I obtain a generic repository that uses EF Core 8's `ExecuteUpdate()` and `ExecuteDelete()`methods while keeping the application layer (and the interface) agnostic from EF Core?

Comment: Do you plan to change ORM in a decade? I think not. Sometimes better do not overcomplicate things. Also generic repository is anti-pattern with EF Core.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv to understand things better:
1. Is it considered OK to reference an ORM in an application layer? In my opinion (but i might be wrong), they could change. So far there have been EF Core, Dapper, NHibernate, etc.

2. Why is the generic repository considered an anti-pattern with EF Core? Do you have any sources that support this thesis?

Comment: @dario how do you plan to form the `expression` value that is expected as input to the `BulkUpdate` and `BulkDelete` methods? If you are able to form that within the repository method definition, then the repository interface can be made agnostic of EF I suppose

Comment: "BulkUpdate" and Delete sound rather generic; I would look at a stored proc and a simple call to execute the proc (from EF). Stored procs always seem like an afterthought even though they can be superior in a given situation.

Comment: 1 ) Yes, do not overcomplicate things, theoretically you will never change horse on the run. 2 ) Because it is abstraction over abstraction. `DbContext` is already UoW, `DbSet` is already repository.

Comment: To accomplish your goal, you have to repeat `SetPropertyCalls` and needed declarations in your layer. Then in repository you have to transform Expression to EF Core's analogues. I can do that, maybe you can do that also, but I think descendants will hate you. I know how complex is task of repeating ExecuteUpdate functionality - you will never change the horse.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I see your point. There would be the need to write a mapping from some agnostic declaration to `SetPropertyCalls`. I have no clue how complex it would be at this point in time. It could become a nice solution to keep the Application Layer agnostic from EF Core, but it could also become ultra-complex and overengineered.

Comment: @Dario you already have a database-agnostic library meant to hide the actual database from your application and let you only work with objects. It's called `Entity Framework`. EF isn't a database driver, it's an ORM and works at a *higher* level than the CRUD data access objects people mean when they talk about "repositories". ORMs try to give the impression of working with in-memory graphs of objects instead of tables and rows. A generic CRUD class on the other hand forces you to work almost directly with tables and rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand your perspective. Entity Framework is abstracting away the database. But wouldn't make it sense as well to abstract the ORM library as well to improve the maintainability for the future in case a new super-cool ORM will be relesed in some years? I'm not saying that mine is the right solution, I'm just trying to reason about it

Comment: But you aren't abstracting anything, you're exposing the innards. And the specific *batch* (not bulk, that's a different thing and there's no bulk delete or update) operations you try to "abstract" depend *entirely* on EF's way of working. If you want to execute raw SQL use Dapper. If you want to compose SQL programmatically, use a SQL generator.

Comment: EF doesn't abstract the database either, that's what ADO.NET does. EF is the object mapper. It uses ADO.NET's abstract DbConnection, DbCommand, DbDataReader objects or the related interfaces, that are implemented by the ADO.NET drivers. The *EF database providers* deal with SQL generation, low-level mapping and the extra parts that aren't abstracted by ADO.NET itself. Except for MongoDB and Cassandra that don't use ADO.NET at all

Answer (score 2):

This is solution for replacing types in expression. I hope it is universal solution and can be used not just for replacing types for `SetPropertyCalls`

Usage in your repository:

```cs
public int BulkUpdate(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query, Expression<Func<ISetPropertyCalls<TEntity>, ISetPropertyCalls<TEntity>>> expression)
{
    var transformed = RepositoryUtils.TransformUpdateExpression<TEntity(expression);
    return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(query).ExecuteUpdate(transformed);
}
```

Introduce interfaces for mimic EF Core classes:

```cs
public interface ISetPropertyCalls<TSource>
{
    ISetPropertyCalls<TSource> SetProperty<TProperty>(
        Func<TSource, TProperty> propertyExpression,
        Func<TSource, TProperty> valueExpression);

    ISetPropertyCalls<TSource> SetProperty<TProperty>(
        Func<TSource, TProperty> propertyExpression,
        TProperty valueExpression);
}
```

Introduce `RepositoryUtils`:

```cs
public static class RepositoryUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> TransformUpdateExpression<TSource>(
        Expression<Func<ISetPropertyCalls<TSource>, ISetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> setPropertyCalls)
    {
        var newExpression = ExpressionTypeMapper.ReplaceTypes(setPropertyCalls,
            new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
                { { typeof(ISetPropertyCalls<TSource>), typeof(SetPropertyCalls<TSource>) } });

        return (Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>>)newExpression;
    }
}
```

And core of this solution `ExpressionTypeMapper`:

```cs
public static class ExpressionTypeMapper
{
    public static Expression ReplaceTypes(Expression expression, IDictionary<Type, Type> replacements)
    {
        var newExpression = new TypeReplacementVisitor(replacements).Visit(expression);
        return newExpression;
    }

    class TypeReplacementVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<Type, Type?> _typeReplacementCache = new Dictionary<Type, Type?>();
        private readonly Stack<Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>> _currentParameters = new();

        public TypeReplacementVisitor(IDictionary<Type, Type> typeReplacement)
        {
            foreach (var r in typeReplacement)
            {
                _typeReplacementCache.Add(r.Key, r.Value);
            }
        }

        private bool TryMapType(Type type, [NotNullWhen(true)] out Type? replacement)
        {
            if (_typeReplacementCache.TryGetValue(type, out replacement))
                return replacement != null;

            if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                if (type.GetGenericArguments().Any(NeedsMapping))
                {
                    var types = type.GetGenericArguments().Select(MapType).ToArray();
                    replacement = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(types);
                }
            }

            _typeReplacementCache.Add(type, replacement);
        
            return replacement != null;
        }

        MemberInfo ReplaceMember(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type targetType)
        {
            var newMembers = targetType.GetMember(memberInfo.Name);
            if (newMembers.Length == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"There is no member '{memberInfo.Name}' in type '{targetType.FullName}'");
            if (newMembers.Length > 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Ambiguous member '{memberInfo.Name}' in type '{targetType.FullName}'");
            return newMembers[0];
        }

        protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
        {
            var replacements = node.Parameters.ToDictionary(p => p,
                p => TryMapType(p.Type, out var replacementType)
                    ? Expression.Parameter(replacementType, p.Name)
                    : p);

            _currentParameters.Push(replacements);

            var newBody = Visit(node.Body);

            _currentParameters.Pop();

            if (ReferenceEquals(newBody, node.Body) && replacements.All(pair => pair.Key != pair.Value))
            {
                // nothing changed
                return node;
            }

            return Expression.Lambda(newBody, replacements.Select(pair => pair.Value));
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            foreach (var dict in _currentParameters)
            {
                if (dict.TryGetValue(node, out var newNode))
                    return newNode;
            }

            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Expression != null && TryMapType(node.Expression.Type, out var replacement))
            {
                var expr = Visit(node.Expression);
                if (expr.Type != replacement)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid replacement of '{node.Expression}' to type '{replacement.FullName}'.");

                var prop = replacement.GetProperty(node.Member.Name);
                if (prop == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Property not found in target type: {replacement.FullName}.{node.Member.Name}");
                return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(expr, prop);
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitNew(NewExpression node)
        {
            if (TryMapType(node.Type, out var replacement) && node.Constructor != null)
            {
                var paramTypes = node.Constructor.GetParameters()
                    .Select(p => p.ParameterType)
                    .ToArray();

                var ctor = replacement.GetConstructor(paramTypes);

                if (ctor == null)
                {
                    var name = replacement.FullName + "." + node.Constructor.Name + "(" +
                                string.Join(", ", paramTypes.Select(t => t.Name)) + ")";
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Constructor not found in target type: {name}");
                }

                var newArguments  = node.Arguments.Select(Visit);
                if (node.Members != null)
                {
                    var newMembers = node.Members.Select(m => ReplaceMember(m, replacement));
                    var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, newArguments!, newMembers);
                    return newExpression;
                }
                else
                {
                    var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, newArguments!);
                    return newExpression;
                }
            }

            return base.VisitNew(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
        {
            if (TryMapType(node.Type, out var replacement))
            {
                var newExpression = (NewExpression)Visit(node.NewExpression);
                var newBindings = node.Bindings.Select(b =>
                {
                    switch (b.BindingType)
                    {
                        case MemberBindingType.Assignment:
                        {
                            var mab = (MemberAssignment)b;
                            return Expression.Bind(ReplaceMember(mab.Member, replacement),
                                Visit(mab.Expression));
                        }
                        case MemberBindingType.MemberBinding:
                        {
                            throw new NotImplementedException();
                        }
                        case MemberBindingType.ListBinding:
                        {
                            throw new NotImplementedException();
                        }
                        default:
                            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                    }
                });

                var newMemberInit = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, newBindings);
                return newMemberInit;
            }

            return base.VisitMemberInit(node);
        }

        private Type MapType(Type type)
        {
            return TryMapType(type, out var newType) ? newType : type;
        }

        private bool NeedsMapping(Type type)
        {
            return TryMapType(type, out _);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.DeclaringType != null)
            {
                var newDeclaringType = MapType(node.Method.DeclaringType);

                if (newDeclaringType != node.Method.DeclaringType ||
                    node.Object != null && NeedsMapping(node.Object.Type) ||
                    node.Method.GetParameters().Any(p => NeedsMapping(p.ParameterType)) ||
                    node.Method.IsGenericMethod && node.Method.GetGenericArguments().Any(NeedsMapping))
                {
                    var newObject = Visit(node.Object);
                    var newArguments = node.Arguments.Select(Visit).ToArray();

                    var newGenericArguments = Type.EmptyTypes;
                    if (node.Method.IsGenericMethod)
                        newGenericArguments = node.Method.GetGenericArguments().Select(MapType).ToArray();

                    if (newObject != null)
                    {
                        var newCall = Expression.Call(newObject!, node.Method.Name, newGenericArguments, newArguments!);
                        return newCall;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var newCall = Expression.Call(newDeclaringType, node.Method.Name, newGenericArguments, newArguments!);
                        return newCall;
                    }
                }
            }

            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }
}
```

---

As I said in comments, generic repository pattern is anti-pattern for EF Core. Do not introduce thing that will slowdown your development and increase project complexity. `ExpressionTypeMapper` is a result of many years of experience and can be challenging for others to support.

Comment: I agree with the above comment about not adding a generic repository or event a repository (Adapter pattern when using EF), because EF is a generic repository pattern for accessing data.